# How to export frozen_inference_graph.pb from a checkpoint in Tensorflow Objectdetection 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

how can I export a trained model to frozen_inference_graph.pb instead of saved_model.pb, because when I use the exporter_main_v2.py that comes with Tensorflow object detection v2 it gives me a folder

```
├─ exported-models/
   └─ my_model/ 
      ├─ checkpoint/
      ├─ saved_model/
            └─ assets/
            ├─ variables/
            └─ saved_model.pb
      └─ pipeline.config
```

and inside the save_model I have saved_model.pb but the issue is that I can't use it alone for inference but I need to use the variable folder that comes with it. that't why I'm asking if theire is a way to export a trained model to frozen_inference_graph.pb to use it for inference without need for variables folderlike in TF1.

Comment: You can see this reference - https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, TF2 does not support the export_inference_graph.py, which would do the exact thing you've asked for - but only for TF1.
The exporter_main_v2.py won't export any frozen graph.

What you can do is freeze your graph using

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
freeze_graph.freeze_graph(...)
```

You can also find the file freeze_graph.py on your computer in tensorflow\python\tools, which is quite well commented on how to use it.
Also, you can have a look at this how to freeze it: [freeze_graph_test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph_test.py)
However, TF2 is not intended to produce frozen graphs any more!

EDIT: Nice workaround can be found [here](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Save-Load-Inference-From-TF2-Frozen-Graph/)

Answer (score 1):

we have the reference in the TensorFlow model git to export model for inference try using it- https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py